# Stuck with BinaryNotes compiler

Tags: java, asn.1

I'm trying to implement some protocol in Java. In order to do that I was using BinaryNotes compiler and their api library but I'm stuck with this example. Here is my asn1 input file:

```
Test
DEFINITIONS ::= 
BEGIN
    OPERATION ::= CLASS
    {
        &Argument   OPTIONAL,
        &opCode Code UNIQUE OPTIONAL
    }
    WITH SYNTAX
    {
        [ARGUMENT &Argument]
        [CODE &opCode]
    }

    OperationA OPERATION ::=
    {
        ARGUMENT Arg
        CODE global:{org(0) operA(1) ver(1) id(1)}
    }

    Code ::= CHOICE
    {
        local INTEGER,
        global OBJECT IDENTIFIER
    }

    Arg ::= SEQUENCE
    {
        operationID INTEGER,
        value   ArgValue
    }

    ArgValue ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(1..25))
END
```

and here is output of bn compiler:

> 1. Compiling file: test1.asn
> 2. line 4:9: unexpected token: OPERATION
> 3. line 6:17: unexpected char: '&'

How should I modify my input asn1 file in order to successefully compile it with bn compiler.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that a CLASS cannot be changed to a SEQUENCE.  That may eliminate error messages in an older compiler, but produces a completely different meaning.

I suggest you obtain a newer ASN.1 compiler that does have support for the 2008 edition of ASN.1.  You can find a list of ASN.1 Tools (some free, some commercial) at http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/links/index.htm.

Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul. On the link you provided as I can see only compiler of OSS Noklava have support for 2008 edition of ASN.1, but unfortunately it isn't free solutions. What If I want to use api library from Bouncycastle and write manually my Java classes. How to deal with CLASS. You said that it cannot be changed with SEQUENCE and I assume that it is same case with SET etc. Thanks in a advance.

Comment: You are correct that the OSS Nokalva compiler is not free, but you can download a free trial to see if that works for you before paying for it.  The purpose for CLASS is to store local information used in determining the content of messages.  CLASS objects never get sent across the line.  If you would like to doing things with an older compiler, you could just eliminate the CLASS definitions.  But you will have to write code to manually handle any constraints that reference the CLASS or information objects of that class.

Answer (score 0):

New ASN.1 classes syntax is not supported in BinaryNotes, sorry!
Also there is no support for `CODE global:{org(0) operA(1) ver(1) id(1)}`
You can try with basic ASN.1 like this:

```
DEFINITIONS ::= 
BEGIN
    OPERATION ::= SEQUENCE
    {
        argument Arg OPTIONAL,
        code Code OPTIONAL
    }


    Code ::= CHOICE
    {
        local INTEGER,
        global OBJECT IDENTIFIER
    }

    Arg ::= SEQUENCE {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you. I was thinking something like you suggest but I/m not was sure do I should use SEQUENCE instead of CLASS. Once more thank You.

Comment: No problem, but you must know BinaryNotes supports only basic common ASN.1 syntax (actually I'm author of this framework :))

Comment: I'm so sorry because You stopped with development of framework :)

Comment: Yeah you right, but I'm not working with ASN.1 anymore. It's legacy Telco domain.